# Nearest neighbour algorithm (or so I think).

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The algorithm is as follows:
Given a graph, we start with some arbitrary vertex, in this vertex the path starts.
From a vertex we are at we proceed to a neighbour vertex along some edge, we're keeping track on not repeating an edge we walked through already. If there are several possible edges, we shall select one as we wish.
As long as it's possible we'll proceed in the graph.
When we arrive at a vertex where we cannot proceed from, we finish.
The algorithm brings back the path which is constructed.

Show that the above algorithm doesn't solve the problem of finding an Eulerian cycle since it can bring back a non eulerian cycle.
Give an example of a simple and connected graph which all of its vertices have even degree, and a path which is not eulerian cycle which can be the outcome of the above algorithm.

Is this the nearest neighbour algorithm or something else?

Anyway, I am not sure of the example that I need to give here.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Consider what happens if you start at a vertex of degree 2 and follow a small cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to work with one part of the proof that every graph with every vertex of even degree has an Eulerean cycle.  This is showing that you need to take a bit of care how you choose the edges when trying to make the cycle, because you might get stuck.  At any vertex that you didn't start at, if you come in there must be a way out because of the even degree.  The problem can be if you come back to the vertex you started at before you have traveled over all the edges.  You are asked to show a graph where this can happen.